# NX from MacOS to Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, nx

I'm using OpenNX on Mac laptop to access freenx server Ubuntu. I'm having authentication error, although I can ssh to the server without using only username and password.

FreeNX is running on the Ubuntu desktop.

```
nxserver --status
NXSERVER - Version 3.2.0-74-SVN OS (GPL, using backend: 3.5.0)
Usage: nxserver <option>
--passwd: Change password
```

Also while I'm checking the ssh log, it keeps saying that user nx is trying to access:

```
User nx from c-98-220-236-7.hsd1.il.comcast.net not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
Oct  4 21:37:28 Cronus sshd[13526]: input_userauth_request: invalid user nx [preauth]
Oct  4 21:37:28 Cronus sshd[13526]: Connection closed by 98.220.236.7 [preauth]
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: it looks like OpenNX is sending 'nx' as your username. are you filling in the 'Login' box with your username as shown here: http://opennx.net/images/stories/screenshots/login.png ?

Comment: I did use my credentials as the same as ssh.